# IIS V6 autoblocking ip

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003-r2

the linux-guy here has a question about IIS v6.

The case is, that i have a site running, when i do some specific tasks on this site ( Like deleting a specific item, three times in a row) the site will break, and a completely blank page will appear. Checking the response headers, i noticed that the server sends a "403 Forbidden: IP address of the client has been rejected."

Through a proxy, i can connect just fine.

Checking the site-options in the IIS manager, shows me that my IP is not blocked globally, its something thats just happening.

Where can i check for this? It happens automatically and the block ends after about 8-12 minutes, every time?

best regards.
Jonas

Answer (score 0):

do you have access to IIS?

i assume blocking occure on web site side (inside ASP code), not in IIS.

please check IIS console, and make sure that there are no blocked IP's. If it's true, you should find database/table or some config file, where stored all blocked IP's. After that, you should get able to find ASP code, which is responsable for blocking....

you also could try make quick search inside all ASP pages for text like: "REMOTE_ADDR" and ".ServerVariables"